# Getting another program's output as input on the fly

Tags: python, c, linux, bash, stdio

I've two programs I'm using in this way:

```
$ c_program | python_program.py
```

c_program prints something using `printf()` and python_program.py reads using `sys.stdin.readline()`

I'd like to make the python_program.py process c_program's output as it prints, immediately, so that it can print its own current output. Unfortunately python_program.py gets its input only after c_program ends.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How much output are you talking about?  There are buffers involved, so anything under 4K will always be a single thing.

Comment: is there no way to decide *when* the buffer should be flushed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just set stdout to be line buffered at the beginning of your C program (before performing any output), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
setlinebuf(stdout);
```

Either one will work on Linux, but `setvbuf` is part of the C standard so it will work on more systems.

By default stdout will be block buffered for a pipe or file, or line buffered for a terminal.  Since stdout is a pipe in this case, the default will be block buffered.  If it is block buffered then the buffer will be flushed when it is full, or when you call `fflush(stdout)`.  If it is line buffered then it will be flushed automatically after each line.

Comment: thank you very much. this helped me in srcds_linux for writing a restarter. i simply put it as plugin into that gameserver and voila.. stdout comes in lines and not in 4k chunks.

Answer (score 9):

What you need is for your C program to call fflush(stdout) after every line.  For example, with the GNU grep tool, you can invoke the option '--line-buffered', which causes this behavior.  See **[fflush](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/nsc/lib/fflush.html)**.

Answer (score 7):

If you can modify your C program, you've already received your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408678/getting-another-programs-output-as-input-on-the-fly/1408730#1408730) but i thought i'd include a solution for those that can't/won't modify code.

[expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) has an example script called [unbuffer](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) that will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try `flush`ing the stdout stream in the cpp program.

Answer (score 1):

All the Unix shells (that I know of) implement shell pipelines via something else than a pty
(typically, they use Unix pipes!-); therefore, the C/C++ runtime library in `cpp_program` will KNOW its output is NOT a terminal, and therefore it WILL buffer the output (in chunks of a few KB at a time). Unless you write your own shell (or semiquasimaybeshelloid) that implements pipelines via pyt's, I believe there is no way to do what you require using pipeline notation.

The "shelloid" thing in question might be written in Python (or in C, or Tcl, or...), using the `pty` module of the standard library or higher-level abstraction based on it such as [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html), and the fact that the two programs to be connected via a "pty-based pipeline" are written in C++ and Python is pretty irrelevant. The key idea is to trick the program to the left of the pipe into believing its stdout is a terminal (that's why a pty must be at the root of the trick) to fool its runtime library into NOT buffering output. Once you have written such a shelloid, you'd call it with some syntax such as:

$ shelloid 'cpp_program | python_program.py'

Of course it would be easier to provide a "point solution" by writing `python_program` in the knowledge that it must spawn `cpp_program` as a sub-process AND trick it into believing its stdout is a terminal (i.e., `python_program` would then directly use `pexpect`, for example). But if you have a million of such situations where you want to defeat the normal buffering performed by the system-provided C runtime library, or many cases in which you want to reuse existing filters, etc, writing `shelloid` might actually be preferable.

Answer (score -1):

ok this maybe sound stupid but it might work:

output your pgm to a file

```
$ c_program >> ./out.log
```

develop a python program that read from tail command

```
import os

tailoutput = os.popen("tail -n 0 -f ./out.log")

try:
    while 1:
        line = tailoutput.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break

        #do the rest of your things here
        print line

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Quitting \n"
```

Comment: Sadly for you, this won't work.  The problem is primarily that the C program's output is buffered, and there's nothing you can do in the Python program to affect that.  You have to fix the C program so that its output is not buffered even when the output goes to a pipe.