# on-the-fly output redirection, seeing the file redirection output while the program is still running

Tags: linux, bash

If I use a command like this one:
./program >> a.txt &
, and the program is a long running one then I can only see the output once the program ended. That means I have no way of knowing if the computation is going well until it actually stops computing. I want to be able to read the redirected output on file while the program is running.

This is similar to opening a file, appending to it, then closing it back after every writing. If the file is only closed at the end of the program then no data can be read on it until the program ends. The only redirection I know is similar to closing the file at the end of the program.

You can test it with this little python script. The language doesn't matter. Any program that writes to standard output has the same problem.

```
l = range(0,100000)
for i in l:
  if i%1000==0:
    print i
  for j in l:
    s = i + j
```

One can run this with:
./python program.py >> a.txt &
Then cat a.txt .. you will only get results once the script is done computing.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408678/getting-another-programs-output-as-input-on-the-fly/1409028#1409028

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`stdout` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdout):

> The  stream  stderr is unbuffered. 
>   The stream stdout is line-buffered
>   **when it points to a terminal**.
>   Partial lines will not appear until
>   fflush(3) or exit(3) is called, or
>   a new‐line is printed.

Bottom line: Unless the output is a terminal, your program will have its standard output in fully buffered mode by default. This essentially means that it will output data in large-ish blocks, rather than line-by-line, let alone character-by-character.

Ways to work around this:

- Fix your program: If you need real-time output, you need to fix your program. In C you can use [`fflush(stdout)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) after each output statement, or [`setvbuf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) to change the buffering mode of the standard output. For Python there is `sys.stdout.flush()` of even some of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering).
- Use a utility that can record from a PTY, rather than outright stdout redirections. [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) can do this for you:

  ```
  screen -d -m -L python test.py
  ```

  would be a start. This will log the output of your program to a file called `screenlog.0` (or similar) in your current directory with a default delay of 10 seconds, and you can use `screen` to connect to the session where your command is running to provide input or terminate it. The delay and the name of the logfile can be changed in a configuration file or manually once you connect to the background session.

EDIT:

On most Linux system there is a third workaround: You can use the `LD_PRELOAD` variable and a preloaded library to override select functions of the C library and use them to set the `stdout` buffering mode when those functions are called by your program. This method may work, but it has a number of disadvantages:

- It won't work at all on static executables
- It's fragile and rather ugly.
- It won't work at all with SUID executables - the dynamic loader will refuse to read the `LD_PRELOAD` variable when loading such executables for security reasons.
- It's fragile and rather ugly.
- It requires that you find and override a library function that is called by your program *after* it initially sets the `stdout` buffering mode and preferably *before* any output. `getenv()` is a good choice for many programs, but not all. You may have to override common I/O functions such as `printf()` or `fwrite()` - if push comes to shove you may just have to override all functions that control the buffering mode and introduce a special condition for `stdout`.
- It's fragile and rather ugly.
- It's hard to ensure that there are no unwelcome side-effects. To do this right you'd have to ensure that only `stdout` is affected and that your overrides will not crash the rest of the program if e.g. `stdout` is closed.
- Did I mention that it's fragile and rather ugly?

That said, the process it relatively simple. You put in a C file, e.g. `linebufferedstdout.c` the replacement functions:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


char *getenv(const char *s) {
    static char *(*getenv_real)(const char *s) = NULL;

    if (getenv_real == NULL) {
        getenv_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getenv");

        setlinebuf(stdout);
    }

    return getenv_real(s);
}
```

Then you compile that file as a shared object:

```
gcc -O2 -o linebufferedstdout.so -fpic -shared linebufferedstdout.c -ldl -lc
```

Then you set the `LD_PRELOAD` variable to load it along with your program:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./linebufferedstdout.so python test.py | tee -a test.out 
0
1000
2000
3000
4000
```

If you are lucky, your problem will be solved with no *unfortunate* side-effects.

You can set the `LD_PRELOAD` library in the shell, if necessary, or even specify that library system-wide (definitely *NOT* recommended) in `/etc/ld.so.preload`.

Comment: Great answer, but can't the buffering mode be changed to line for the environment? This is exactly what I don't like to do, change the source of all my programs. :( This should be OS controlled, don't you agree? The screen command is probably not good since I use qsub to submit jobs to large servers, or nohup on smaller servers. But, I will try it!

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to modify the behavior of an existing program try stdbuf (part of coreutils starting with version 7.5 apparently).

This buffers stdout up to a line:

`stdbuf -oL command > output`

This disables stdout buffering altogether:

`stdbuf -o0 command > output`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This is the simplest solution and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered piping to tee?

```
./program | tee a.txt
```

However, even tee won't work if "program" doesn't write anything to stdout until it is done. So, the effectiveness depends a lot on how your program behaves.

Comment: I just tried ./program | tee a.txt and ./program | tee -a a.txt. None works.

Comment: Does the program write anything before it ends? Is it flushing its buffers? What does a simple `./program` do then?

Comment: The program can be anything as long as it puts an output to the terminal. It can be a C program or a python script etc. I had the same problem in all of them. If I try to redirect the standard output to a file I can only read the file once the program ended.

Comment: Maybe the output is on stderr: ./program 2>&1 | tee a.txt

Comment: Still not working. Anyway, the program runs well, I have the same problem with many other programs and scripts for months. There may be a general principle involved.

Answer (score 1):

If the program writes to a file, you can read it while it is being written using `tail -f a.txt`.

Comment: The program writes to the standard output not to a file and the stdout must be redirected to a file. I checked your command with the little script above and it is not working. It is simple to circumvent this problem by appending to a file then closing that file after each append, but it is not what I want. What I want is to read standard output redirection on a file while the file is still generated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that most programs check to see if the output is a terminal or not. If the output is a terminal then output is buffered one line at a time (so each line is output as it is generated) but if the output is not a terminal then the output is buffered in larger chunks (4096 bytes at a time is typical) This behaviour is normal behaviour in the C library (when using printf for example) and also in the C++ library (when using cout for example), so any program written in C or C++ will do this.

Most other scripting languages (like perl, python, etc.) are written in C or C++ and so they have exactly the same buffering behaviour.

The answer above (using LD_PRELOAD) can be made to work on perl or python scripts, since the interpreters are themselves written in C.

Answer (score 0):

The [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) command from the `expect` package does exactly what you are looking for.

```
$ sudo apt-get install expect
$ unbuffer python program.py | cat -
<watch output immediately show up here>
```