# Modifying "... | tee -a out.txt" to stream output live, rather than on completion?

Tags: bash, output, stdout, stderr

I would need to output the output of a command on a file. Let's say my command is `zip -r zip.zip directory` , I would need to append/write (any of these options would be fine) to a file (let's say `out.txt`). I got `zip zip.zip directory | tee -a out.txt` so far, but it doesn't seem to work, it just writes the whole output when the command is over... How can I achieve this?

Thanks ;)

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? Exactly what happens instead?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Edited ;)

Comment: Ahh! So what you're seeing is *buffering*. If you were writing a big enough file, you'd see it in incremental chunks... it's just that those chunks are bigger than a line.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009).

Comment: and this question arguably duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500515/on-the-fly-output-redirection-seeing-the-file-redirection-output-while-the-prog, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee, or the like.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And can I avoid buffering in a `zip` command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Background (ie. Why?)

Redirections are immediate -- when you run `somecommand | tee -a out.txt`, `somecommand` is set up with its stdout sent *directly* to a `tee` command, which is defined by its documentation to be unbuffered, and thus to write anything available on its input to its specified output sinks as quickly as possible. Similarly, `somecommand >out.txt` sets `somecommand` to be writing to `out.txt` literally *before* it's even started.

What's **not** immediate is flushing of buffered output.

That is to say: The standard C library, and most other tools/languages, *buffer* output on stdout, combining small writes into big ones. This is generally desirable, inasmuch as decreases the number of calls to and from kernel space ("context switches") in favor of doing a smaller number of more efficient, larger writes.

So your program isn't really waiting until it exits to write its output -- but it *is* waiting until its buffer (of maybe 32kb, or 64kb, or whatever) is full. If it never generates that much output at all, then it only gets flushed when closing the output stream.

---

#### Workarounds (How? -- GNU version)

If you're on a GNU platform, and your program is leaving its file descriptors the way it found them rather than trying to configure buffering *explicitly*, you can use the `stdbuf` command to configure buffering like so:

```
stdbuf -oL somecommand | tee -a out.txt
```

defines stdout (`-o`) to be line-buffered (`L`) when running `somecommand`.

---

#### Workarounds (How? -- Expect version)

Alternately, if you have `expect` installed, you can use the `unbuffer` helper it includes:

```
unbuffer somecommand | tee -a out.txt
```

...which will actually simulate a TTY (as `expect` does), getting the same non-buffered behavior you have when `somecommand` is connected directly to a console.

Comment: Hum ok ! Much clearer ! Thanks for the explanation ! So is it possible to unbuffer the `zip` command? (I'm on MacOS)

Comment: ...well, have you *tried* `unbuffer zip zip.zip directory`?

Comment: By the way, personally, I have `unbuffer` on OS X by way of having a copy of `expect` installed with macports. I assume Homebrew will carry `expect` as well.

Comment: I'll asap ;) Thanks for this awesome answer and sorry for this kind of noob question ;)

Comment: (similarly, a MacPorts install of coreutils creates a `gstdbuf` command -- so there's a good chance that if you *did* `port install coreutils`, you could `gstdbuf -oL zip zip.zip directory` successfully).

Comment: Perl has a module for working with `zip` archives (`IO::Compress::Zip`); it has flush capabilities built-in.

Comment: @l'L'l, *nod*; Python has a zip module as well -- lots of options if the OP's looking to use a different toolchain.

Comment: To Charles Duffy & @l'L'l  : I'm trying to use bash as much as possible, but I could use Python to ;) In fact, my main goal is to display the output in a AppleScript which doesn't support unbuffering  (not sure?) so I wanted to write the output in a file and then read that file in the AppleScript.

Comment: @Blaxou, ...so, I'd suggest trying to break down the problem in such a way as to either isolate it to AppleScript or eliminate AppleScript from it. That is: Test whether you can unbuffer output from `zip` to a file *without* AppleScript being involved. If you can, the only remaining question you have is one about AppleScript, and you can ask it with details unrelated to AppleScript factored out.

Comment: `unbuffer ./my_daemon.py > log.log` finally works for me! ANY other solution is not working...

Comment: @RecolicKeghart, that would be the case only if `my_daemon.py` writes its logging to the TTY. It's generally not great practice for programs run as daemons to depend on having a TTY at all -- if it's something you control the code of, maybe you might fix it there.

Comment: @recolic, ...btw, Python has its own unbuffer flag; see the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable, and the `-u` flag to the interpreter (`python -u ./my_daemon.py`).

Comment: wrt `stdbuf` - its manpage says: NOTE:  If  COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does for example) then that will override corresponding changes by 'stdbuf'.

Comment: @stason, right, but tee adjusts its output to be unbuffered -- it's not the problem here; it's the thing left of tee that's buffering, and thus which needs stdbuf applied.

Comment: I couldn't get it to produce unbuffered output - probably because in my particular case I needed the final stream writing to the file to also set `O_SYNC|O_DIRECT` on the file descriptor to tell NFS to sync across clients immediately, so unfortunately `stdbuf` didn't help.  The application has its stdout re-opened with these flags, but `tee` then doesn't. So need to look for another workaround.

Comment: @stason, please consider posting a reproducer for your case as part of a new question. (Also, have you straced tee and confirmed that it really is reading the input, and that it's truly output buffering that's the problem? I'm doubling down here because every time I've seen this it's been something to the left on the pipeline; and your NFS flags shouldn't matter until a write is actually being performed -- they're moot while libc buffering is happening)

Comment: Yes, my apologies, it did feel that my comment was going on a tangent to the original matter at hand and warrants a new separate discussion. Thank you for the diagnostics suggestions, Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try option `command > out.log 2>&1` this log to file everything without displaying anything, everything will go straight to the file

Comment: Does it appends/writes to the file even of the command isn't over?

Comment: @Blaxou, of course it does -- a command that's exited can't write *anything*. (As an aside, this is part of why using `kill -9` unnecessarily is bad form: When you terminate a program without giving it a chance to clean up after itself, it can't flush its buffers and write content it's been saving up to its stdout... or anywhere else).