# Read from another process' output stream

Tags: java, process, stream

i wanted to read the output-stream of a c-Application in my Java program. *iremoted* (available here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200505051207/http://www.osxbook.com/software/iremoted/download/iremoted.c)) is a C-Application that puts out seperate lines like "0x19 pressed" if a button on my Apple Remote is pressed. If i start the iremoted program everything is doing well and these separate lines are shown on my screen everytime I pressed a button.
Now I wanted to read the output-stream of the c-application in my Java application to process inputs of the Apple Remote in Java projects.
Unfortunately i don't know why *no input is regocnized*?

I tried it with a simple HelloWorld.c program and my program responded as intended in this case (prints out  HelloWorld).

*Why doensn't it work with the iremoted program?*

```
public class RemoteListener {


public void listen(String command) throws IOException {
    
    String line;
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Could not execute program. Shut down now.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    
    Reader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inStreamReader);
   
    System.out.println("Stream started");
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Stream Closed");
}




public static void main(String args[]) {
    RemoteListener r = new RemoteListener();
    try {
        r.listen("./iremoted"); /* not working... why?*/
        // r.listen("./HelloWorld"); /* working fine */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: How does iremoted open its output stream? Are you sure it's writing to its stdout and not stderr or the terminal directly?

Comment: I edited the noteworthy sections to fprintf(stdout, .....) anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stdout` is buffered and it's not automatically flushed if you are not writing to screen. Add:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after:

```
printf("%#lx %s\n", (UInt32)event.elementCookie,
    (event.value == 0) ? "depressed" : "pressed");
```

Comment: Can I achieve the same output otherwise, not editing the source of the C-Program?

Comment: @BlackCurrant look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408678/getting-another-programs-output-as-input-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 1):

iremoted is likely writing to stderr if a hello world program works.  You would want the error stream in that case.  I'm not sure how this works for your hello world case - I think you're doing the wrong thing here:

```
 new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
```

should be

```
 new InputStreamReader(process.getOutputStream());
```

or

```
 new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
```

Comment: new InputStreamReader() takes an instance of InputStream as argument, that can not be cast to OutputStream.