# how to change .class file to a text file

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I'm trying to make a java program which executes java files and gives output in the text field. I've used Runtime class to compile the .java file .So how do I get the output from that newly made class file.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Y://CodeSave.java");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Y://CodeSave.class>output.txt");
```

Comment: Dynamically compiling and executing user code is a huge security risk. May I ask why you want to do this? Perhaps there's a simpler and safer way

Comment: The title and body of your question do not seem to match.  Are you asking how to execute a Java program and capture its output stream, from within a different Java program?

Comment: I was trying to add 4 other duplicates and someone reopened this. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957337/read-from-another-process-output-stream

Comment: @feelingunwelcome yes, this question may be a dupe, but not of the one you linked (reading a text file)

Comment: I was adding 4 more about reading the outputstream of external processes, that was a copy/paste error. you need to reclose this at least with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957337/read-from-another-process-output-stream

Answer (score 0):

In the general case: `exec` returns a [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance which has accessors ([`getOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--), etc.) for the I/O streams. You read from / write to those streams.

But: In your code you've used `>output.txt`. That's a *shell* feature. If you want to do it that way, you need to spawn a shell, not the `java` tool directly, and have the shell execute that command line. (A search for spawning/execing a shell should find you lots of examples.)

Comment: sir, can you give an exampe.I tried that but can't get through

Comment: @Akash: Frankly, a search should turn up a dozen or more of them.

Answer (score -1):

Using Runtime.exec is definitely not the right way to do it, for various reasons. Examples are that both java and javac rely on environment variables which you can't pass that way.

First of all, I'd ask myself if I really needed to do this. Compiling and executing dynamically created code is a huge security risk.

But if you're sure you need to do it, here's what I'd do.

- Move your sources to a dedicated temporary folder
- Use the [ToolProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) api to compile your sources
- Use a dynamic throwaway ClassLoader ([ByteBuddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) may help you there) with a [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) to load and execute your code from within your application