# Java, How can I Automatically Save Prints into a Text File

Tags: java, printing, console

Firstly, sorry the question is not phrased well.

I am wondering if there is a was of a java program to automatically store what the program prints out in a text file.

example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

How would I get the program to save what is printed in the console, in this case "Hello World!" to appear in a text file, for instance in notepad.

Any help is appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux/Unix you could copy stdout to file using *tee*

See :[How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Otherwise use log4j to write into a log file.