# Redirect python script stdout + time to file AND to screen with arguments

Tags: python, time, stdout, tee

I'm having some problems with combining python, time and tee.

I have a script *script.sh* which contains following line:

```
{ time python extractPassRate.py -i DataPaths/background.list -o PassRates/background.csv ; } 2>&1 | tee log.log
```

However, when I do:

```
source script.sh
```

The terminal just hangs.

Interestingly when i replace that line with:

```
{ time python extractPassRate.py ; } 2>&1 | tee log.log
```

(that is, if I remove the python script arguments)
or

```
{ time python extractPassRate.py -i DataPaths/background.list -o PassRates/background.csv ; } 2>&1
```

(not saving to log.log)

The script works.

Is there something wrong with the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Googling around, I found the solution here, by Matthew Alpert:
[How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

It seems that was due to a buffering problem.

Matthew's answer says:

> The program unbuffer, part of the expect package, will solve the
>   buffering problem. This will cause stdout and stderr to write to the
>   screen and file immediately and keep them in sync when being combined
>   and redirected to tee. E.g.:
>
> $ unbuffer program [arguments...] 2>&1 | tee outfile

That worked for me