# How to save Kur log messages onto a txt file from console?

Tags: bash

When you run `kur data mnist.yml`, though it is a simple batch of data to be displayed, it is very long and you may be unable to see the log messages at the very beginning.

One way to see the message at the beginning is to save the log message into a txt file.

Could I add some code onto `kur data mnist.yml` to save all the log message?

Comment: See: [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/418896/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, this link is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this issue:

`kur data mnist.yml 2>&1 | tee my.txt`

As a result, the log message is saved into `my.txt` on the current directory.