# Bash output all stdout both to console and file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to output all `stdout` and `stderr` both to console and to a file. I know about `./script | tee somefile` , but that doesn't work for me. I want it to do it automatically, without me piping it from the console. I've tried

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1 | tee somefile
echo "..."
```

but that didn't work. What would be the correct solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout

Comment: @soft87: I know that. I mentioned, that I don't want to pipe it from the console, like described in that post, I want it to always do it. So even if I run `./somescript`, I will get both the file and the console output

Comment: Are you wanting to do this for *all* commands you run, or just for one particular script.  If the former, either run `diary` or run tee in the background reading from a pipe and redirect your shell's io streams to that pipe.  If the latter, just invoke tee in the script.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: All commands. I may have multiple `echo` commands, and I don't want to have to pipe each of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical solution is to add something like this at the top of the script:

```
test -z "$REXECED" && { REXECED=1 exec $0 "$@" 2>&1 |  tee -a somefile; exit; }
```

You might also like:

```
test -t 1 && {  exec $0 "$@" 2>&1 |  tee -a somefile; exit; }
```