# How to get stream output in command window and text document simultaneously

Tags: python, ping, command-window, stream-operators

Using `os.system('ping 127.0.0.1 -t >> new.txt')`. I am able to get the ping result in `new.txt` document. How to get the ping result in command window and text file **at the same time** in case of stream output like this...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer:I am looking for windows Maurice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with os.system('powershell "ping 127.0.0.1 -t | tee ping.txt')