# Redirecting the darknet program's result to log file

Tags: shell, redirect, stdout, darknet

I'm trying to redirect the results of darknet(yolo) program to my log file.

But there are some troubles in redirecting the result.

I tried `./darknet detect cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights image.jpg > log.txt`, but it doesn't work.

And also other redirecting methods are not working.

I think the results of darknet program is not printed to stdout but printed to somewhere.( I don't know where it is.)

So, I have no idea to solve this problem.

Please help me...

How do I get this results in forms of file?

Comment: Could you try redirecting standard error stream also? `./darknet detect cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights image.jpg 2>&1 > log.txt`

Comment: By curiosity, what is this script ? Is it public ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot Sorry, what do you mean 'this script'? darknet? darknet is public

Comment: @Inian  Thank you for your help. But it still doesn't work...

Comment: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Comment: @GillesQuenot Thank you! I solved this problem. 
The problem was opencv. The results are represented in forms of picture(because of opencv), so I couldn't redirect them.
Thus, without opencv, I could get desired data.

Comment: Which repo of darknet is this?
Alexeyab or PJreddie?

Answer (score 0):

This appends all the standard output into a file. Remove `2>&1` if you don't want to log standard errors.

```
./darknet detect cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights image.jpg 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt
```

Detail info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418899/3257147).

Comment: in the log.txt output what's the information about mAP?