# Output progress over time in hashcat

Tags: passwords, password-hash, hashcat

I am analysing the amount of hashes cracked over a set period of time.
I am looking to save the current status of the crack every 10 seconds.

'''

Recovered........: 132659/296112 (44.80%) Digests, 0/1 (0.00%) Salts
   Recovered/Time...: CUR:3636,N/A,N/A AVG:141703,8502198,204052756 (Min,Hour,Day)
   Progress.........: 15287255040/768199139595 (1.99%)

'''

I want these 3 lines of the status saved every 10 seconds or so.
Is it possible to do this within hashcat or will I need to make a separate script in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Getting the status every 10 seconds

You can enable printing the status with `--status` and you can set the status to prints every X seconds with `--status-timer X`. You can see these command line arguments on the [hashcat options](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat) wiki page, or `hashcat --help`.

Example: `hashcat -a 0 -m 0 example.hash example.dict --status --status-timer 10`

---

#### Saving all the statuses

I'm assuming that you just want to save everything that gets printed by hashcat while it's running. An easy way to do this is just copy everything from stdout into a file. This is a popular s/o question, so we'll just use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/418899/2521402).

To be safe, let's use `-a` which appends to the file, so we don't accidentally overwrite previous runs. All we need to do is put `| tee -a file.txt` after our hashcat call.

---

#### Solution

Give this a shot, it should save all the statuses (and everything else from stdout) to `output.txt`:

```
hashcat -a A -m M hashes.txt dictionary.txt --status --status-timer 10 | tee -a output.txt
```

Just swap out A, M, hashes.txt, and dictionary.txt with the arguments you're using.

If you need help getting just the "Recovered" lines from this output file, or if this doesn't work on your computer (I'm on OSX), let me know in a comment.

Comment: Yes this worked fine for me, thank you. I'm using ubuntu and had no issue. One thing I would add is it is a good idea to create an output file for the cracked hashes too as they are also lumped in the created file.  `hashcat -a A -m M hashes.txt dictionary.txt --status --status-timer 10 -o cracked.txt | tee -a output.txt
`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andrew Zick's answer, note that for machine-readable *status*, hashcat has native support for machine-readable output - see the `--machine-readable` option. This produces tab-separated output like so:

```
STATUS  5       SPEED   111792  1000    EXEC_RUNTIME    0.007486        CURKU   1       PROGRESS        62      62     RECHASH  0       1       RECSALT 0       1       REJECTED        0       UTIL    -1
STATUS  5       SPEED   14247323        1000    EXEC_RUNTIME    0.038953        CURKU   36      PROGRESS        2232   2232     RECHASH 0       1       RECSALT 0       1       REJECTED        0       UTIL    -1
STATUS  5       SPEED   36929864        1000    EXEC_RUNTIME    1.661804        CURKU   1296    PROGRESS        80352  80352    RECHASH 0       1       RECSALT 0       1       REJECTED        0       UTIL    -1
STATUS  5       SPEED   66538858        1000    EXEC_RUNTIME    3.237319        CURKU   46656   PROGRESS        28926722892672  RECHASH 0       1       RECSALT 0       1       REJECTED        0       UTIL    -1
STATUS  5       SPEED   63562975        1000    EXEC_RUNTIME    3.480536        CURKU   1679616 PROGRESS        104136192       104136192       RECHASH 0       1       RECSALT 0       1       REJECTED        0       UTIL    -1
```

... which is exactly what tools like Hashtopolis use to provide a front-end to hashcat output.

For machine-readable *output*, the options `--outfile`, and `--outfile-format` are available. See the `Format` section of the output of `hashcat --help` for the options to `--outfile-format`:

```
- [ Outfile Formats ] -

  # | Format
 ===+========
  1 | hash[:salt]
  2 | plain
  3 | hex_plain
  4 | crack_pos
  5 | timestamp absolute
  6 | timestamp relative
```