# Save Radare2 terminal output into text file for Mac

Tags: bash, malware, radare2

I am trying to use Radare2 to save opcode sequences from PE32 files. Does anyone know how I can save the output Radare2 prints onto terminal after I call the "pd" command onto a text file? I am also wondering if there might be a way to do this in python as well using the r2pipe library.
[image]

Comment: As it seems you are just asking for how to redirecting your command output into a file, does this answer your question: [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)? For Python and r2pipe you may have a look into [R2 Wiki](https://r2wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/home/radare2-python-scripting/#r2pipe).

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I just did [command] > textfile.txt on terminal. Thanks!