# log file during the process of python script

Tags: python

I have python script

```
test.py
```

When I run in my Linux via command panel it shows the log (what script is doing)

```
python test.py
```

But when I run it in this way I cannot see the log file until the script is done:

```
nohup python test.py 1> logifle.log 2>&1 &
```

How I can see the log inside the logfile.log during the script is working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Comment: No its not the same

Comment: Does this help: `stdbuf -oL python test.py 1> logfile.log 2>&1 &` ?

Comment: Why does using `tee` or `tail -f` not solve your problem?

Comment: python test.py | tee output.file

this just start writing log in the command line

Comment: That’s what you asked for, isn’t it?

Comment: No i want to have log in the file, not in the command line, i wanna close the commandline and have the active process so when i open the log file i can see what the script is doing

Comment: Did you try using `tail -f logfile.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-u` flag; from `python --help`:

```
-u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
         this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
```

Need to do this:

```
nohup python -u test.py 1> logifle.log 2>&1 &
```