# How to redirect (partially) output to a file with exceptions

Tags: bash, io

I would like to redirect output to a file how described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout) but with an exception: let's suppose I do not want to store all the lines which start with the character `r`.

Specifically, I execute:

```
./command | tee /tmp/output.txt
```

and I get all the printed lines in the file. How to modify the instruction to allow exception?

Comment: Try: `./command | grep -v '^f' | tee /tmp/output.txt`

Comment: that works perfectly. To conclude, I always use grep to build my own exception. Just answer to the question: it may be useful for someone else more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for an output process substitution:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" {o..u} | tee >(grep -v '^r' > outputfile)
o
p
q
r
s
t
u

$ cat outputfile
o
p
q
s
t
u
```