# Node.js command line arguments "<" and ">"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `test.js` file with the following content:

```
let i = ''
process.stdin.on('data', (c) => (i += c))
process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  const { EOL } = require('os')
  const lines = i.split(EOL) 
  console.log(lines)
})
```

I figured out that when I run this line bellow  I read from `input.txt` and output to `output.txt`. Everything works just fine.

```
node test.js < input.txt > output.txt
```

However, I cannot find any info in node.js official docs about command line arguments like `<` and `>` . Am I looking in a wrong place? Is there somewhere a full list of possible arguments of this type and how to use them? Thanks.

Comment: ``<`` and ``>`` have special meanings in terminals, and what's happening here is unrelated to Node.JS. See [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/input-output-redirection-in-the-shell).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` and `>` are not command line arguments to `node`. Rather, in most shells, they are part of a feature known as [I/O Redirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), which you can use to redirect the input and output of a program. According to the link above:

> Redirection simply means capturing output from a file, command, program, script, or even code block within a script and sending it as input to another file, command, program, or script.

If you would like more information about actual command line arguments you can pass to `node`, you can run `node --help` or visit [the official docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/synopsis.html).

Comment: No problem, glad to help!