# Print stdout and stderr in terminal and redirect to 2 different files

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr

The answer(s) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout) explains how to print stdout and stderr to the terminal, while also redirecting them to a file:

```
program [arguments...] 2>&1 | tee outfile
```

How could this be extended if stdout and stderr should be redirected in 2 different files ?

Comment: Have you tried `tee outfile outfile2` ?

Answer (score 1):

With [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
program >(tee stdout.log) 2>(tee stderr.log >&2)
```