# Is there a way to double print a file in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, printf, cat

I'm new to Linux and programming. My problem is the following: I have a file listing 3 columns. I want to swap the first and the last column, print it to prompt AND to a new file in one line. So I swapped the columns and printed it to prompt OR to a file.

`$ awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = t; print; } ' OFS=,  liste.csv`

This is my base line to print it to prompt. But it seems impossible to print it to a new file in the same command line.
Does anyone have the idea?
Here are some examples that didn't work:

`$ awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = t; print; } ' OFS=,  liste.csv | >liste2.csv`

`$ printf "$(sudo awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = t; print; } ' OFS=,  liste.csv > liste2.csv)"`

`$ cat $(sudo awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = t; print; } ' OFS=,  liste.csv > liste2.csv)`

I think you catch the drift of what I ask.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks alot. double printing will do the job just perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tee` command as mentioned in [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Or, redirect it within `awk` itself by adding `print > "liste2.csv"` in addition to the existing `print` for displaying on `stdout`

Answer (score 1):

*print it to prompt AND to a new file in one line*

This sound like task for [tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee). Assuming

```
awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = t; print; } ' OFS=,  liste.csv
```

does produce correct output to standard output, this

```
awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $3; $3 = t; print; } ' OFS=,  liste.csv | tee liste2.csv
```

should write to `liste2.csv` and standard output