# How to show the output for the execution for any command and/or script in stdout and file but keeping the color in the stdout?

Tags: bash, io, stdout

For *some* commands, in the terminal they print with some colors in the *stdout*, for example:

```
git status
mvn help:help -Ddetail=true
gradle build
Any Linux command (ls [-...], etc)
```

**Note**: it applies for **scripts** that contain:

- Executions of Linux commands
- Executions for tools commands
- Executions other scripts

Therefore the following is possible:

```
./mvnw help:help -Ddetail=true
./gradlew build
./customscript.sh
```

Until nothing is new and all work how is expected, therefore:

- *linux_command*
- *tool_command* (maven, git, gradle etc)
- `script.sh` (execute linux/tools commands and other scripts)

So if any of them print in the terminal (**stdout**) some colors, it is the default behavior according each command/tool

Now if I want see the output in the terminal (as above) **and** write it to some file, according with:

- [How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Therefore is possible do in general

```
"linux_command" | tee [-a] "/some/path/log_file.log"
"tool_command"  | tee [-a] "/some/path/log_file.log"
"script.sh"     | tee [-a] "/some/path/log_file.log"
```

And it works how is expected, **but** the output in the terminal (*stdout*) does **not** include the colors anymore.

**Question:**

- How to show the output for the execution for **any command** *and/or* **script** in `stdout` and file but keeping the color in the `stdout`?

Same behaviour when the *pipe* and `tee` were not included and of course meanwhile write the content in the `.log` file.

**Note** I did do a research about the `script` command

- [How to trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/how-to-trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe)

but it overrides the `script.sh` content

I need a general approach, it for any command and/or `script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

`unbuffer` is your command

`unbuffer git status | tee`   => I keep my color

`git status | tee`   => back in no-color world

You can have  :

- on Debian/Ubuntu  with `expect` package
- on Fedora with `expect` package
- On MacOS with brew.sh       `expect` package
- On MacOS with macports.org  `expect` package

Source of **expect** package is https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index

FYI , if your problem is only limited to Git ,
Git has a flag to force color .

```
git -c status.color=always status
```

Comment: Does `unbuffer` work with any command and script, right? - sadly my mac is very old, I can't upgrade homebrew. Is other way to install in MacOS? El Capitan. For Linux I am OK in other machines

Comment: pls if you know other approach without install any dependency would be perfect - it mostly for Windows where I execute the scripts after of the execution of the `bash` command available from `Git` (declared in the PATH)

Comment: @ManuelJordan you are using `bash`  in which context ? WSL 1 ? WSL 2 ? Cygwin ?

Comment: about `Windows 10` I use `ConEmu` (for multiple tab pages) and `Git` is added in the OS' `PATH`, so when I open `ConEmu` and even `cmd` and I write the `bash` command it loads the `Git` environment and is possible use a good set of default of Linux commands - but of course is not possible 'install' some packages - or is possible?