# Redirect python -v output to a file

Tags: python

I am trying to inspect the modules which are loaded from my script and their respective locations that is why I am trying to run

```
python -v mysrcipt.py
python -vv mysrcipt.py
```

Since I want to compare how the imports are loaded in two different scripts I want to redirect the verbose output which looks like this

```
# code object from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/__pycache__/translate.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'botocore.translate' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f182affa748>
import 'botocore.handlers' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f182afe0a90>
# trying /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/loaders.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/loaders.abi3.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/loaders.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/botocore/loaders.py
```

to a file. To do this I have tried

```
python -v mysrcipt.py > file.txt
python -v mysrcipt.py 2>&1 > file.txt
```

but the only thing that is written to the file are the logs of the script and not the verbose output regarding the imports.

How can I successfully redirect the imports related output to a file?

Comment: `python -v myscript.py &> file.txt` works fine on my machine.

Comment: Works on my machine too @KlausD. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `>` only write `STDOUT` to the file (changed the standard output location)

if you want write all of the outputs (like stdout, stderr and etc) in to file use this command and pipe (`|`) all of them to `tee`:

```
python3 -v main.py  2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

or

```
python3 -v main.py  > output.txt 2>&1
```

`1` for `stdout` and `2` for `stderr`.

only write `stdout`:

```
python3 -v main.py 1> output.txt
```

only write `stderr`:

```
python3 -v main.py 2> output.txt
```

both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
python3 -v main.py > output.txt  2>&1
```

So when you use `2>&1` you are basically saying Redirect the `stderr` to the same place we are redirecting the `stdout`. And that is why we can do something like this to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to the same place

more info:

[How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/515624)

[How to redirect output to a file and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)