# Get logs from a specific file within container in Kubernetes cluster using kubectl log command

Tags: kubernetes, logging, containers, bitnami

I have an application which stores logs in a file at a configurable location.
Let's say `/abc/pqr/application.log`

Application is being migrated to Kubernetes where it will run in a single pod. If I run `kubectl log <pod-name>`, I get anything that gets printed on `stdout` which I can redirect to a file. I want to do the other way around, I have a file containing logs at above location and I want `kubectl logs <pod-name>` to print logs from that file.

For example, if run `kubectl logs kafka` for a kafka pod deployed using [bitnami/kafka](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka), I get logs from `/opt/bitnami/kafka/logs/server.log`. I want to mimic this behavior.

Comment: Inside the docker container, what happens if you configure the app to write its logs on `/dev/stdout`? Should (in theory) redirect the output on `stdout`, at least on a linux os. I never tried inside a docker container so I don't really know if it works or not inside, one but I'd make a try

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it works inside centos docker container and it is similar to the first solution suggested by @moonkotte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl logs` command takes everything from `stdout` and `stderr`, so you need to supply logs there.

It's a common practice when containerised applications write their logs to `stdout` and `stderr`.

This way there are two main options:

1. Adjust the application so it writes logs to `stdout` and file as well.
   E.g. using shell it can be done with `tee` command.

   Please find a [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout) with description of the command.
2. Use a sidecar container which will be getting logs from file and translating them into its own `stdout`.
   Please find [Using a sidecar container with the logging agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-logging-agent)

Useful link about kubernetes logging (including containers):

- [The Complete Guide to Kubernetes Logging](https://sematext.com/guides/kubernetes-logging/#how-does-logging-in-kubernetes-work)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor apologies, it was long weekend for me.

Comment: @moonkotte thanks for the answer. I have a design restriction - one container per pod, so can't use sidecar container but I will go with the first approach.